# The requested URL /< was not found on this server. on Nagios core Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, nagios

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server running nagios3 from the apt repo.
I get the message `The requested URL/< was not found on this server`
The config file in `etc/apache2/sites-available` which is soft linked to `sites-enabled`config;

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName monitor.server.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.com.bundle.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

ServerName monitor.novarumcloud.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
ScriptAlias /nagios3/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
Alias /nagios3/images /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images
Alias /images /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/images
Alias /nagios3/stylesheets /etc/nagios3/stylesheets
Alias /stylesheets /etc/nagios3/stylesheets
Alias /nagios3/js /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/js
<DirectoryMatch (/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs|/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3|/etc/nagios3/stylesheets)>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
    AuthName "Nagios Access"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users
    require valid-user
</DirectoryMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Why is this happening? I'm sure it's probably a simple config error on my part. I have SSL certificates installed and only port 443 open too

Comment: Are you sure about the location of +ExecCGI?  Normally that would be required for your nagios3/sbin folder, where the cgi scripts are located.  Also, are you seeing this error when first attempting to connect, or from a sub page; and do you get a login first?

Comment: I get a login first, I'll try the folder you suggest as I don't know where +ExecCGI is

Comment: May I ask you to write the line of code in the virtual host file?

Comment: The directory that has the +ExecCGI option set, holds your cgi files.  Look for the file 'status.cgi'.

Comment: I changed the directory to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3` after doing a find. Still get the same error after login. I've edited above

Comment: When you type in the URL, are you adding the port and nagios folder?  <site>:443/nagios3/

Comment: No, just the URL of the server https://monitor.server.com

Comment: Did you try http://monitor.server.com:443/nagios3/  ?

Comment: yes I just get the same response